# What is the difference between a twistor and bispinor?

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, twistor

Reading the book on General Relativity written by R.M. Wald I (tags according to Wald's book) encountered the concept of a twistor

$$ Z = (\omega^A, \pi_{A'}) \tag{14.1.9} $$

which looks very much as a Dirac bispinor (I assume here that the ' notation is the same as the $\dot{}$ notation):

$$ \Psi = \left( \begin{array}{c} \psi_A \\ \zeta^\dot{A} \end{array} \right) $$

or even more like its barred counterpart

$$\bar{\Psi} = \Psi^\dagger \gamma_0  = (\psi^A, \zeta_\dot{A}) $$

Interestingly, the equation quoted by Wald which fulfills the twistor is ($\partial_{A{A'}} = \sigma^\nu_{A{A'}}\partial_\nu$)

$$\partial_{AA'} \omega^B = - i \epsilon_A^{\,\,B} \pi_{A'} \tag{14.1.10}$$

which is different from the Dirac equation which comprises 2 equations

$$ \partial^{A\dot{A}} \psi_A = -i m \zeta^\dot{A} \quad\text{and}\quad \partial_{A\dot{A}} \zeta^\dot{A} = -i m \psi_A$$

The attempt to bring the twistor equation into Dirac equation form does not work well out because upon contraction of the indices A and B the right side turns into zero since the "spinor metric tensor" is antisymmetric.

The twistor equation is different from the Dirac equation, why was it never considered except in areas like Quantum Gravity or similar ? Is it because the Dirac equation provided many confirmed predictions and particles which might follow the twistor equation haven't been found yet respectively the twistor cannot be understood as standard representation of the Poincare' group ?

In other words what makes a twistor so particular although it looks like a Dirac bispinor in a perhaps not very common (but nevertheless equivalent) representation for bispinors?